# Youtube PHP API Upload a Video

Tags: php, api, authentication, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

I'm trying to upload a video to youtube using the PHP API (V3).

My problem:
I dont want to authenticate a specific user, but have my application use a server-key (not client ID) and upload to the user that owns the application.

My code:

```
    $DEVELOPER_KEY = '';
    $APPNAME = "";
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
    $client->setApplicationName($APPNAME);
    $videoPath = "";
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();

    $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
            $client, $insertRequest, 'video/*', null, true, 1 * 1024 * 1024
    );
```

Error:

> User Login required

I dont want to use client authentication...there is no specific user involved.
Is there a way to authenticate server-key only (on behalf of the app owner)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to defer the auth call: `$client->setDefer(true);`. [See the full example here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) (switch to the PHP tab). Also, double check the developer key. It should be the `server key`. Without IP limitations. Or double-check ip limitations.

Comment: You are missing the point... That is exactly what I used but I don't want to authenticate a user (it's not relevant since I only have an app) everything in the example is based on user token and server key doesn't work

Comment: Just to verify yourself, please open [this link in a browser](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=&key=XXX). The XXX is a `Server API key`.

Comment: does this help? (result):
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.parameter",
    "reason": "missingRequiredParameter",
    "message": "No filter selected.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": ""
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "No filter selected."
 }
}